# How to use FFTW wisdom from modern Fortran

Tags: fortran, fftw

I want to use the FFTW wisdom system to remember FFTW plans between jobs. The use of wisdom from a C program is documented here: http://www.fftw.org/fftw2_doc/fftw_2.html  For C, the relevant string would be modified to `FFTW_MEASURE | FFTW_USE_WISDOM`.  I have tried to emulate that here:

```
!! to compile: gfortran -O3 --fast-math -I/usr/include -o usewisdom usewisdom.f90 -lfftw3
```

```
Module FFTW3
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
    include 'fftw3.f03'
End Module FFTW3

Program usewisdom
  use FFTW3
  integer (kind=c_int), parameter :: nx=2048,ny=2048,np=ny/2+1
  real (kind=c_double) :: omega(ny,nx)=1.d0
  complex (kind=c_double_complex) :: fftomega(np,nx)
  ier=fftw_import_wisdom_from_filename("wisdom")
  print *,"wisdom output should not be 0:",ier
  call dfftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(fwd,ny,nx,omega,fftomega,&
       &FFTW_PATIENT | FFTW_USE_WISDOM)
  call dfftw_execute_dft_r2c(fwd,omega,fftomega) !rem clobbers omega

End Program usewisdom
```

but gfortran doesn't like the string:

```
gfortran -O3 --fast-math -I/usr/include -o usewisdom usewisdom.f90 -lfftw3
usewisdom.f90:16:21:

    &FFTW_PATIENT | FFTW_USE_WISDOM)
                 1
Error: Syntax error in argument list at (1)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: you are using FFTW3 while you are following the FFTW2 Documentation !! .

Comment: @M.Chinoune any suggestions as to how this should be done in FFTW3?

Comment: Just follow the documentation of [FFTW3](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Accessing-the-wisdom-API-from-Fortran.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Modern Fortran interface documentation](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Overview-of-Fortran-interface.html#Overview-of-Fortran-interface):

> Multiple planner flags are combined with `ior` (equivalent to ‘`|`’ in C). e.g. `FFTW_MEASURE | FFTW_DESTROY_INPUT` becomes `ior(FFTW_MEASURE, FFTW_DESTROY_INPUT)`. (You can also use ‘`+`’ as long as you don’t try to include a given flag more than once.)

You should thus include the `FFTW_USE_WISDOM` planner flag as follows:

```
  call dfftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(fwd,ny,nx,omega,fftomega,&
     &ior(FFTW_PATIENT, FFTW_USE_WISDOM))
```

or

```
  call dfftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(fwd,ny,nx,omega,fftomega,&
     &FFTW_PATIENT + FFTW_USE_WISDOM)
```

Note that a similar syntax for combining flags can also be used for Legacy Fortran as described in [this section of the documentation](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/FFTW-Constants-in-Fortran.html#FFTW-Constants-in-Fortran).

Comment: The second form given in your answer does the trick.  The first form makes gfortran unhappy: 'gfortran -O3 --fast-math -I/usr/include -o newJet newJet.f90 -lfftw3
newJet.f90:219:26:

        &ior(FFTW_PATIENT, FFTW_USE_WISDOM))
                          1
Error: ‘j’ argument of ‘ior’ intrinsic at (1) must be INTEGER